# JQuery Animating Sprites Issue

Tags: jquery, html, css, navigation, sprite

I figured it out.  I just added:

```
    $("#switch").css('background-position','0px 10px')
```

before the second function of .hover().

---

I'm making a JQuery navigation menu that uses sprites as the buttons.  What I'm aiming for is a row of paint tubes that roll out when you hover over them, and get squeezed when you click them.  I've gotten everything set up except I'm running into problems when someone presses one, then drags (The button animates from the bottom right of the sprite to the top left instead of moving only left).  I'm not sure how to animate something only using the x axis, and making the sprite animate to the top with a time of 0 makes the animation mess up.

Here's my javascript.  The ids #home, #about etc. are the individual buttons,and the #NavBar is the div that contains them.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#home, #about, #members, #gallery, #press, #campaign, #calendar, #network, #join, #request, #contact").hover(function () {
        $(this)
        .stop(true,false)
        .width(200)
        .animate({"backgroundPosition":"(3px 0px)"},300)
    },
        function () {
        $(this)
        .animate({backgroundPosition:"(-35px 0px)"}, 300)
        .animate({width:"105"}, 300)
    });

    $("#home, #about, #members, #gallery, #press, #campaign, #calendar, #network, #join, #request, #contact").mousedown(function () {
        $(this)
        .animate({backgroundPosition:"(3px -40px)"},0)
    });

    $("#home, #about, #members, #gallery, #press, #campaign, #calendar, #network, #join, #request, #contact").mouseup(function () {
        $(this)
        .animate({backgroundPosition:"(3px 0px)"},0)
    });

    $("#NavBar").mousedown(function () {
        $(this)
        .width(200)
    });

    $("#NavBar").mouseup(function () {
        $(this)
        .width(105)
    });

});
```

Here is my HTML:

```
<div id="NavBar">
  <ul>
    <li class="tube" id="home"><a href="_Home.html"></a></li>
    <li class="tube" id="about"><a href="_About.html"></a></li>
    <li class="tube" id="gallery"><a href="_Gallery.html"></a></li>
    <li class="tube" id="campaign"><a href="_Campaign.html"></a></li>
    <li class="tube" id="press"><a href="_Press.html"></a></li>
    <li class="tube" id="calendar"><a href="_Calendar.html"></a></li>
    <li class="tube" id="members"><a href="_Members.html"></a></li>
    <li class="tube" id="network"><a href="_Network.html"></a></li>
    <li class="tube" id="join"><a href="_Join.html"></a></li>
    <li class="tube" id="request"><a href="_Request.html"></a></li>
    <li class="tube" id="contact"><a href="_Contact.html"></a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Here is my CSS:

```css
body, div, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, ul, ol, li, dl, dt, dd, img, form, fieldset, input, textarea, blockquote {
    margin: 0; padding: 0; border: 0;
}

#NavBar {position:absolute; width:105px; cursor:pointer; top:5px;}
#NavBar ul li {list-style: none;}
#NavBar ul li a { display: block; width: 105px; height: 40px;}
#NavBar ul li a:active {background-position: -35px 40px}

#home     {background: url(Tubes/Home.png)     -35px 0px no-repeat;}
#about    {background: url(Tubes/About.png)    -35px 0px no-repeat;}
#members  {background: url(Tubes/Members.png)  -35px 0px no-repeat;}
#gallery  {background: url(Tubes/Gallery.png)  -35px 0px no-repeat;}
#press    {background: url(Tubes/Press.png)    -35px 0px no-repeat;}
#campaign {background: url(Tubes/Campaign.png) -35px 0px no-repeat;}
#calendar {background: url(Tubes/Calendar.png) -35px 0px no-repeat;}
#network  {background: url(Tubes/Network.png)  -35px 0px no-repeat;}
#join     {background: url(Tubes/Join.png)     -35px 0px no-repeat;}
#request  {background: url(Tubes/Request.png)  -35px 0px no-repeat;}
#contact  {background: url(Tubes/Contact.png)  -35px 0px no-repeat;}
```

Comment: @Greg Pettit: You can use syntax highlighting hints to tell prettify to highlight a code block as a certain language - see http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/75019 for info.

Comment: Please don't put "resolved" in the title or edit your solution into the question. The convention here is to post it as an answer instead.